# How to configure AWS CLI v2 in Windows 10?

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-10, configure

I just installed AWS CLI v2 on my Windows 10 machine. I tried configuring using `aws config` command and selecting all the default values. When I run the command, it doesn't throw any error. But when I look for the `.aws` folder in my user directory, I can't find it. It's not there. I tried enabling hidden items. But still not there. What is the issue? How do I fix this?

I ran `aws configure list` and this is the output

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key                <not set>             None    None
secret_key                <not set>             None    None
    region                <not set>             None    None
```

Comment: Where did you look for the folder? Check under `%userprofile%`

Comment: @Paolo I did check in `%userprofile%`. I can't find it.

Comment: When running the `aws configure` command, the `.aws` directory is supposed to be created in the user home directory, however, despite the aws command taking and regularly listing the values, no such directory exists. Noone seems to know where the files actually end up stored, but its not where the documentation claims it should be. This is likely an issue with Windows permissions, but there so far seem to be no solutions on the web, yet many people with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You were saying **I tried creating the credentials**, but `aws configure` is used to configure

- AWS Access Key Id
- Secret Access Key

which are already created for a User. I don't think you can create credentials using this command.

To Create the credentials, you can use any of the following:

1. IAM Web Console.
2. Using `aws iam create-access-key --user-name <iam-user-name>`. This returns a JSON object in the following format:

```
{
    "AccessKey": {
        "UserName": "XXXXX",
        "AccessKeyId": "XXXXX",
        "Status": "Active",
        "SecretAccessKey": "XXXXX",
        "CreateDate": "2020-06-05T11:09:16Z"
    }
}
```

then you can set these using `aws configure`.  Once completed, there should be two files available in the `.aws` folder.

- `config`
- `credentials`

Comment: I.m sorry for the wrong usage of words. I was trying to configure, not create credentials. As I mentioned in the question, I was looking for `.aws` folder which supposed to be created running `aws configure` command with default values which I can't find.

Comment: What's the output of echo %userprofile%  and dir %userprofile%

Comment: The output for `echo %userprofile%` is just empty and the output for `dir %userprofile%` does not contain `.aws`

Answer (score 0):

As you had credentials and you already installed CLI for windows. Try configure from command prompt.

1. Open your command prompt and let's check the cli version. type -  aws --version

We check the CLI version here:

[image]

2. now type "aws configure" it will asked for both
   AWS Access Key Id:
   Secret Access Key:
   aws configure command:

[image]

That's it. It's best practice to use IAM user instead of root user.